# Tool to display nodes with a certain tag?

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

Are there any tools available which allow you to display nodes on a map based on what tags they have? For instance, if I wanted to see all the nodes on a map with "traffic_signals=*", say a dynamic version of this map that I could zoom in and out of:

https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/?key=traffic_signals&filter=all#map

Comment: Do you already know http://overpass-turbo.eu/?

Comment: Yes, found it yesterday and was going to put it up here today! Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question and as per scai's comment above, I have used overpass-turbo.eu ...it works a treat